# Xamarin Forms simple button animation

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a button image that will be animated when clicked. I want the image to loop through four images or frames over the course of a few seconds or so. 
This is where I am stuck. I am trying to use the new ImageButton for this, but I have found nothing in the reference for swapping between images, only changing size, rotating etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple

I am out of ideas for this, if anyone could help it would really make my day.

I can easily change a normal button text when clicked, but so far, changing the button image a few times is not working using the ImageButton.source property. I am guessing what I need would look something like:

> async void ImageChange_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> {
>
> ```
>      await  imageChangeButton.Source =  loopAnimation();
> ```
>
> }

Where loop animation would go through the sequence of images and return to the original one on the button, Only I have no way of doing that.

Comment: Why not just make a loop inside ImageChange_Clicked and foreach item in the loop set the image source? You can add Task.Delay(1000) between each iteration if you watch to control the animation speed.

Comment: Thank you!!! Exactly what I needed. Works perfectly.